# Reinstalling MAAS - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, maas

I'm new here in the forum, I wonder if anyone ever had a problem reinstalling MAAS in Ubuntu 16.04? Because when I try to reinstall without erasing dbconfig I'm getting the errors below.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23875672/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Run `dpkg --configure -D 777 maas-region-controller` and [edit] your question with the output.

Comment: I can not edit the exit questions of the package with the command you passed.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont think I get what you mean,  can you try to rephrase it? :)

Comment: Well I'm having trouble trying to reinstall the MAAS (Metal As A Service) server on Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS when trying to reinstall the packages that make up the MAAS I'm getting error in the maas-region-controller package when it starts configuring the package To complete the installation.
You can see the errors in the link below
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23875672/

Comment: Have you purged maas or just uninstalled it?